Upgrading from 23.10 to 24.04 Desktop with seperate /home partition failure
It appears a happy migration is not possible if you have the /home directory in a separate drive/partition. You can only install 24.04 to a single drive. Trying to mount the /home partition after deleting the new /home directory as root brings everything back as expected but Thunderbird & Firefox both fail and cycle resets (which stops their removal) as they are now snaps. Trying the advanced setup allows the /home partition to be set with the / partition but does not allow the boot partition to be set. Is there a work-around yet?
I currently have a default install on sda. Trying to get around the snap issue I removed Thunderbird & Firefox then mounted sdb1 on /home. Reboot and all is fine. Reinstall Thunderbird & Firefox to now fix the snap images and now get from either: .... is already running. To use .... You must first close the existing....
A snap stop .... returns error: snap .... has no services.
A ps aux | grep .... gives an incrementing PID which is changing too fast to match.
Guiverc, thank you for your persistence. The only issue I still have is with the background restarting PID's of Thunderbird & Firefox that stops me from running them. I realise there are other browsers & email clients but hey. They appear to be cycling every second.
Oh silly me. When I type PS aux | grep thunderbird it is reporting the PID of my grep request. I tried the same referring to a 'whatever' process and had the same result. So no process hidden in the background. Just the app thinks it is actually running when it is not. A snap issue?
Latest update. Solved
Uninstall Thunderbird & Firefox via the App Centre. Within a terminal, "sudo find / -type d -name thunderbird". Delete all references (except /run/user/1000 references due to file locking). Same for Firefox. Reboot and re-install via the App Centre. Perform initial launch for file creations & setup. This could be overkill but hey, it worked.

What do you mean by migration when /home is on a different partition, as I've been using that without issue on upgrades to 24.04... There was an issue with the ubuntu-desktop-installer discovered in QA that caused some install options to use forced format (making migration more difficult) due to insufficient time existing to fix a regression.. but your details are unclear & I don't know if that's your issue, as that can be worked around. Your issue maybe just user-error or config-error but you've provided few specifics as to what you're encountering.

I have /home on a separate drive. From the install, the choices only give a single drive install or if you select the Advanced one you cannot select the 'boot' partition to move on. If the single drive direction is taken then after the /home drive is mounted, Thunderbird & Firefox go into a panic mode with changing PID's so they cannot be killed or uninstalled. Does this help?

Ubuntu 23.04 Desktop & later use the ubuntu-desktop-installer where I've not performed any QA using multiple drives... Whilst up to 23.10 provided a legacy ISO that allowed use of ubiquity [installer] that is no longer available. I have installed using "Something else" with ubiquity to multiple drives but that was long ago on i386 hardware so I've not done it recently.  If it was me, I'd just install the system using / on the drive you want, ESP if required (if /home you want on another drive; ignoring that for now) and ensure the install works; then boot live and change

... the install to what you want there, ie.   I'd modify the file-system table (/etc/fstab) so /home/ is where you want it to be, and the system will thus ignore (shadow) the /home/ directory on / partition... and you have what you want.  Me, I'd boot the system and confirm you have got what you want, then reboot into live media and finally delete the /home/ directory on the / partition.... which yes could have been done earlier; but in case you make a mistake; this allows for an easier backout of changes..  This is one way around the installer not allowing what you want.

FYI:  I don't know what ubuntu-desktop-installer doesn't provide the same feature as ubiquity... I'd expect it would, and if it didn't I"d be raising a bug report asap as that is a regression which should be fixed.. alas the systems I perform QA testing on with amd64 only have single drives in them, which is why that testing was only performed (by me) on older i386 or 32-bit hardware (ie. up to Ubuntu 19.04 only; which received the last i386 ISOs, not counting re-spins of 18.04)

This is a Q&A or Question and Answer site, so please remove the 'answer' from your actual question, and paste it below in the answer section of this page. Everyone is welcome to write their own answers (some questions/answers are posted on sites like this for information sharing purposes!), and you can gain some rep. in doing so.
